# Creating factory for generics in java

Tags: java, generics, factory

I want to make a factory for my generic type classes. I have the Device base class:

```
public abstract class Device<T> {

T stateVariable;
private String name;

public Device(T stateVariable, String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.stateVariable = stateVariable;
}

// getters & setters 


abstract void changeActualState(T changeVariable);

}
```

The TV class is extends the Device:

```
public class TV<T> extends Device<T>{


public TV(T stateVariable, String name) {
    super(stateVariable, name);
}

@Override
void changeActualState(T changeVariable) {
    if(!changeVariable.equals(stateVariable)){
        System.out.println("The TV now is " + changeVariable);
        setStateVariable(changeVariable);
    }
}
}
```

And also the Therme class which extends also the Device class:

```
public class Therme<T> extends Device<T> {

public Therme(T stateVariable, String name) {
    super(stateVariable, name);
}

@Override
void changeActualState(T changeVariable) {
    if(!changeVariable.equals(stateVariable)){
        System.out.println("The temperature changed to " + changeVariable);
        setStateVariable(changeVariable);
    }
}
}
```

And I also have an enum:

```
enum Type{
    TV, Therme
}
```

I want to make a factory, depending on the type from the enum to make the specific class.

Comment: Just try something, then ask for guidance when you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of options to implement this. Here's one which embeds device creation directly in the enum:

```
enum Type {
    TV {
        @Override
        protected <T> BiFunction<T, String, Device<T>> deviceCreator() {
            return device.TV::new;
        }
    },
    Therme {
        @Override
        protected <T> BiFunction<T, String, Device<T>> deviceCreator() {
            return device.Therme::new;
        }
    };

    protected abstract <T> BiFunction<T, String, Device<T>> deviceCreator();

    public <T> Device<T> createDevice(T stateVariable, String name) {
        return this.<T>deviceCreator().apply(stateVariable, name);
    }
}
```